# No apps with domain entitlements

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I am trying to integrate deep linking through universal links. Everything is settled up nicely on developer account. Associated domains are also enable on the app id.

On server side myapp.com/apple-app-site-association is available. But apple search validator always throws this error.

I am not sure what it means exactly..?

If any one can help me that would be really great.

Thanks

Comment: Having the same problem here. Currently having the apple-app-site-association in the domain root like you. Did you try putting it in /.well-known/apple-app-site-association ? I just thought it could be worth a shot.

Comment: I tried it on both places but I'm still with that problem.

Answer (score 6):

...and it possibly always will. I actually don't know exactly what that tool is checking for, because domains that definitely work with Universal Links (https://google.com, https://jet.com, for example) still throw errors on Apple's validator. Officially, it is comparing your website's `apple-app-site-association` file to your app's listing on the App Store, so if the version of your app that is publicly available does not yet have Universal Links entitlements, that could be contributing to an error. However, Universal Links will still work fine with local builds.

If your links are correctly opening your app, there is probably no need to worry.

**UPDATE**: you might also consider using a free deep linking service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) because then you don't need to worry about these technical implementation details. Also, there are many situations where Universal Links don't actually work (in the Facebook app, for example) and you'll need to add edge case handling that Branch already has built in.

Comment: I have checked on device and found it's not working.

Comment: Can we see your actual live AASA file for reference?

Comment: sure but right now it's not showing in correct format. Link is https://www.threadshare.nyc/apple-app-site-association

Comment: {
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "8DZ4LB2G56.com.streatmanagement.threadshare",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: That looks like a rich text file, which would definitely explain why Universal Links are failing. It needs to be pure JSON.

Comment: How..? I have removed extension .rtf from that file

Comment: before few hours it was pure JSON only still it was showing error and not working in device.

Comment: Simply removing the .rtf extension isn't enough to strip out all the embedded formatting data. You need to save it correctly straight from the editor. Also, see the update in my answer for an alternative method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126024/discussion-between-anil-kukdeja-and-alex-bauer).

Comment: That is a useful point that it is comparing to the app in the app store.  Most people will hit this in development as creating this file is the next logical step after adding the entitlements.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for me in development though.  Anything obviously wrong with my file here?  https://hivepass.app/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error but universal link is working for me as I corrected my TeamId. 
In my case the apple-app-site-assocition file TeamId was wrong. I used my Certificate TeamId which you can see in Xcode/keychain access

You should use your TeamID of the account not your TeamId of your certificate.

To get your TeamID Login to developer account Click on Account > Membership.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer:

But this may happen when there are errors in the domain.

Be sure you are using https not the http and the apple-app-site-association must be exactly in the root of the directory and should not contain any extension. There should not be any redirection to the page.

Validate the domain with apple [here](https://search.developer.apple.com/)