# Error no apps with domain entitlements

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I added .entitlement file in app, also enabled associated domains for project and bundle ID. Also did all required server side setup and getting this error.

[image]

Comment: You have Googled the error message and found nothing useful?

Comment: I stuck from 2 days, googled a lot. So finally posted question.

Comment: So nothing e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087119/no-apps-with-domain-entitlements) is helpful? That's worth mentioning - otherwise people may just give you the same advice again

Answer (score 2):

From the official page about Universal Links, the App Search API Validation Tool is presented as *"Find out if your website is ready for universal links and get recommendations on website optimization."*

[Universal Links for Developers - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the "App Search API Validation Tool", **not** the "Universal Links Validation Tool" (which doesn't exist from Apple). The results from this tool have no connection to whether Universal Links work or not.

Could you update your question with the contents of your `apple-app-site-association` file (or a link to its location) and screenshots of the relevant configuration items in Xcode?