# Setting Universal Links

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

In order to make the connection between a website and an iOS app, I am trying to set Universal Links. But I am facing some issues. At this point I am using [this tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/) to check that things are OK.

The URL I am checking looks like this:

```
http://www.example.net/MyApp/
```

And the results I get look like this:

```
Title         Passed         .....

Description     Recommended  .....

Image           Passed  https://....../rock.jpg     

Touch Icon      Passed  http://......./custom_icon.png  

Link to Application     Action required

                    Could not extract required information
                    for application links. Learn how to
                    implement the recommended Universal Links.

                          Error cannot fetch app site association
```

As one can see, the problem is the "Link to Application" not working. But I have set a file *apple-app-site-association* inside *.well-known/* under the root directory of the website.

And the *apple-app-site-association* file looks like this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": ["1122..8899.mybundle.example.MyApp"]    ,
         "paths": [ "*" ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": ["1122..8899.mybundle.example.MyApp"]
   }
}
```

Is there something in what is above looking wrong or suspicious.

I have never really used Universal Links before, so I am not confident that I am doing the right thing.

Comment: @ Eric Aya; I have tried your second suggestion, it doesn't make any difference. I don't understand what you mean in your first comment.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get this error:
"Error cannot parse app site association"
instead of this one:
"Error cannot fetch app site association"

Comment: Well then I don't know. Looks like there's good informations at https://gist.github.com/anhar/6d50c023f442fb2437e1 Have a look, maybe it could help you clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that need to be done for universal links.

1. Setting up the apple-app-site-association in the .well-known/ under the root directory.
2. Add your domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) inside your xcode project settings as capabilities.

The second step tells that the app has to consider this ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) as the base URL and the paths which you provide in the apple-app-site-association file will be appended to this base URL (EG: "www.example.com/*")

**To do this go to project settings -> Signing and Capabilities -> Associated Domains -> Hit + and add you website as a domain like this (applinks:example.com)**

Comment: By the way, here is a question: what should be set in the associated domain?
webcredentials:example.com
or
applinks:example.com

Comment: applinks:example.com

Comment: OK, I'll try, I have seen both in various documents.

Comment: I tried and it makes no difference. As a matter of fact, I think the tool I am using now is only taking care of the correctness of the server side (i.e. apple-app-site-association file. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah i understood. I think the key is just appID and not appIDs

Comment: I am now getting:

    Error no apps with domain entitlements
    The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

Comment: I checked with google.com in the apple tool and it throws error for that website as well. If the email link opens your app then I think it is good to go. I personally use branch.io for AASA validation.

There is a similar question already which you can refer as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087119/no-apps-with-domain-entitlements

Comment: OK. I will take a look then. Thanks.